# Why am I getting the dateformat wrong on server side?

Tags: php

I have to send datetime from my php page to my server. The date-time is getting displayed correctly in my php page. However, when I submit the form; just the date gets transferred and not the time. I can see in the form-request sent to the server; I can see only the date and not the time.

Here is what I have done:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>
                                <input type="hidden" id="trans_date" name="trans_date" value=<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>><br>
```

Here, the echo is displaying date-time correctly. However, when I submit the form; I am just able to see todays date ie. 2016-01-11.

Whats the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose your `value` attributed in quotes.

The date format you use has a space between the date and time, so the browser only considers the first part the value, and the second part is basically "another attribute". Surrounding the date and time with quotes fixes this.

Comment: You are right. I made a silly mistake there. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I am today date using .. date('Y/m/d');
I get 2016-01-11
I want to get the same date but for next year.. ie. 2017-01-11. What should I do?

Comment: I got it using this.. echo date('Y/m/d',strtotime('+1 year'));